# corrupted images after uploading through 2G/GSM network

Tags: android, ftp, gsm, apache-commons-net

I built an app that take pictures and upload them to THe server, i'm using Apache commons FTP library to upload them.
when i'm using wifi the images are uploaded without any issues...
but when i'm using 2G mobile network to send them half of them the server recieve them as corrupted images.

i set the file type to binary file type.

is there a way to determine whether the images got corrupted or not.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine whether the images got corrupted or not, compare the images received by the server with the corresponding ones on your Android device.

In order to determine why the images got corrupted, you may run WireShark or tcpdump on the server and snoop an upload. Careful examination should reveal if the problem is

- within the server software (you see the complete image in the network traces), or
- in the device or the network (you see a broken image in the network traces).

You also may experiment with image sizes (in terms of bytes) and check if there is a size boundary from which on you see problems. That might give clues on where to look further